# Mongodb string to date conversion

Tags: php, database, mongodb, laravel-5.1

Below is my sample mongodb collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ed32f4070577ec56a56b9f"),
    "log_id" : "180308",
    "issue_id" : "108850",
    "author_key" : "priyadarshinim_contus",
    "timespent" : NumberLong(18000),
    "comment" : "Added charts in the dashboard page of the application.",
    "created_on" : "2017-08-16T18:22:04.816+0530",
    "updated_on" : "2017-08-16T18:22:04.816+0530",
    "started_on" : "2017-08-16T18:21:39.000+0530",
    "started_date" : "2017-08-02",
    "updated_date" : "2017-08-02",
    "role" : "PHP",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-09-29T15:27:48.069Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-09-29T15:27:48.069Z"),
    "status" : 1.0
}
```

I need to get records with help of *started_date* , by default I will give  two dates in that i will check `$gt` and `$lt` of started date .

```
        $current_date =  '2017-08-31';
        $sixmonthfromcurrent ='2017-08-01';

     $worklogs = Worklog::raw ( function ($collection) use ($issue_jira_id, $current_date, $sixmonthfromcurrent) {
     return $collection->aggregate ( [ 
              ['$match' => ['issue_id' => ['$in' => $issue_jira_id],
                          'started_date' => ['$lte' => $current_date,'$gte' => $sixmonthfromcurrent] 
                    ] 
              ],

              ['$group' => ['issue_id' => ['$push' => '$issue_id'],
                          '_id' => ['year' => ['$year' => '$started_date'],
                          'week' => ['$week' => '$started_date'],'resource_key' => '$author_key'],
                          'sum' => array ('$sum' => '$timespent')] 
              ],
              [ '$sort' => ['_id' => 1] 
              ] 
        ] );
     } );
```

If I run this query I am getting this type of error:

```
Can't convert from BSON type string to Date
```

How to rectify this error?

Comment: "started_date" : "2017-08-02" is not of type ISODate(), look at your type in the database, it should be string. the $lte and $gte should work in the match query. But then it throws an exception in the $group operation because you try to extract the week from a string.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, how to use that string in my $group operation,

Answer (score 0):

The only field in your **$group** that I see as troubling is the field *week*.
The *year* you could extract by doing a **$project** before your **$group** aggregation:

```
$project: {
        year: { $substr: [ "$started_date", 0, 4 ] }, 
        issue_id: 1,
        author_key: 1,
        timespent: 1
    }
```

if you know that the date string will always come at this format. Of course you cannot do a substr operation for finding out the week.

It would be easy though if your field *started_date* would be an actual ISODate(), then you could use exactly what you wrote as you probably already saw in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation-date/). 
If you need the field *week* very bad, which I imagine you do, then I'd suggest you convert your field *started_date* to an ISODate(). 
You can do that with a bulkWrite:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('yourDatabaseName');
var requests = [];
db.yourCollectionName.find().forEach(doc => { 
    var date = yourFunctionThatConvertsStringToDate(doc.started_date);
    requests.push( { 
        'updateOne': {
            'filter': { '_id': doc._id },
            'update': { '$set': {  
                "started_date": date
            } }
        }
    });
    if (requests.length === 500) {
        db.yourCollectionName.bulkWrite(requests);
        requests = [];
    }
});

if(requests.length > 0) {
     db.yourCollectionName.bulkWrite(requests);
}
```

Load this script directly on your mongodb server and execute there.
Hope this helps.